# My pages disappeared from the list

Tags: pages

I have a serious problem.

Last weekend I moved some websites from an old server to other more powerfull. It's a new installation.

I'm using a AWS EC2 Ubuntu 14.04 connected to a RDS MySQL.

In this new server the websites is working fine, but when I try to edit a page, noone appears on page list, as you can see on the image.

It's happening in all sites, including in a new site that I've installed right now.

Anybody knows what's going on?

Thanks a lot

Emanuel

*** I did a test and discovered that the problem is that I'm using a RDS MySQL instance instead of a localhost. :(

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've solved the problem.

There was a wrong parameter that cause an error on this specific select. The strange thing that just this select was affected.

I needed to increase sort_buffer_size and be careful with max_sort_length.

[]'s

Emanuel